# Is there any way to open the applications in two systems at same time?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

To develop an application in power apps there is a team of two members. The application is not accessible by two people at the same time in two systems.  I wanted to know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: I think this feature is not available on PowerApps, As it is a website, you could use version control to save an update the code but I believe what you are looking for is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this option is not currently available in Powerapps. As a workaround, you can duplicate the app so that two users can work on two different independent screens and copy/paste controls to the master app once the development is completed.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is called **co-authoring**, which is not yet available as other answers suggested. But Microsoft is working/delivering continuously, we can expect the improvements in ALM at the earliest so that multiple developers can collaborate at the same time.

> **Co-Authoring Notifications to Prevent Unintentional Overwrites**
>
> In the past, it was possible for app makers who share ‘edit’ rights to be able to overwrite the changes of others unintentionally. We have prevented this now with the new co-authoring notifications. With this release, app editors will be notified when the app is being revised, and will not be permitted to make additional changes until the app has been saved and closed. This is just one step forward towards our longer-term roadmap goals for complete application lifecycle management where co-authoring will be further enhanced. Stand by for more on ALM coming soon!

[Read more](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-newest-release-hits-home-with-toprequests/)

> **Co-authoring isn't supported. One author at a time, please.**
>
> You can corrupt an app or over-write others’ changes if more than one person modifies the same app at the same time. Close the app before someone else edits it.

[Reference: Common issues and resolutions for PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/common-issues-and-resolutions)

You can maintain two versions of apps & manually merge them (copy/paste screens/controls), one good thing is you can find issues using [App-Checker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/accessibility-checker) & fix it quickly.